# BackboneJS updating url with routers?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a router like this

```
var Router= Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "firstname/:name":"getfname",
        "lastname/:lname":"getlname",
        "age/:age":"getage",
        "*actions":"defaultRoute"
    }
})
```

and when linking to them i want them to be

```
<a href="lastname/lastname>last name</a>
<a href="firstname/firstname>firstname</a>
<a href="lastname/lastname2>last name 2</a>
```

how do I make it happen so when I click lastname the url will go to url.com/lastname/lastname then when I click on firstname it goes to url.com/lastname/lastname/firstname/firstname and when I click again on the second lastname it will update the url to lastname/lastname2/firstname/firstname keeping the firstname parameters in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use pushState and define your root file

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/myapp/"})
```

Also don't forget about right usage of quotation marks

```
<a href="lastname/lastname">last name</a>
<a href="firstname/firstname">firstname</a>
<a href="lastname/lastname2">last name 2</a>
```